# Show that the upper semicontinuous has a maximum

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, semicontinuous-functions

[image]

I found a proof of showing, given that $D$ is compact, if the function $f$ is upper semicontinuous then f achieves a maximum on $D$. But I have a question about the very last sentence:

> and thus $M<\infty$.

How could this conclusion is obtained, since just before two lines it is said that "It may be that $M=\infty$"?

Could anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps "It may   be that $M=\infty$" would have been better written as "We need to verify that $M$ is finite".

Comment: It is as @DavidMitra said. There is the possibility of $M$ being infinity, but then he proved that this not happens.

Comment: @Tomás Yes that is also what I thought. But how did he rule that out? I just did not quite get that.

Comment: He showed that there is a point $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=M$ and because (probably) your function has image on the reals, you can conclude.

Comment: Reading through the proof more carefully, it seems at the outset that $M<\infty$ is assumed when he writes $M-1/n\le f(x_n)\le M$, assuming $f$ is real-valued.  [This argument](http://books.google.com/books?id=6-rbkb_7OFoC&pg=PA209&lpg=PA209&dq=upper+semicontinuous+has+a+maximum&source=bl&ots=u_PWraaKmA&sig=PduBg_Rn62f1TcX193DKouJ_iRs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=b1opUaKUDJGi8ASz94H4Cw&ved=0CEsQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=upper%20semicontinuous%20has%20a%20maximum&f=false) seems more coherent to me.

Comment: To see that $M$ is finite, note that $U_n = f^{-1}(-\infty,n)$ is an open cover of $D$ such that $U_n \subseteq U_{n+1}$ and by compactness there is $N$ such that $D \subseteq U_N = f^{-1}(-\infty,N)$. // Where does this excerpt come from?

Answer (score 1):

The $M-\frac{1}{n}\leq f(x_n)\leq M$ idea is dubious to me. This already assumes $M$ is finite (proved earlier somewhere?). The idea of the argument still works, though, but we begin with a maximising sequence of $f$, say, $x_n,n\in\mathbb N$. This sequence exists due to how supremum is defined. We have
$$f(x_n)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\sup _{x\in D} f(x) =:M $$
Due to compactness, we have a convergent subsequence $x_{k_n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}x_*\in D$ and due to semicontinuity
$$ M = \lim _{n\to\infty} f(x_n) = \limsup_{n\to\infty} f(x_{k_n}) \leq f(x_*) \leq M$$
which immediately excludes the possibility of $M=\infty$ and $f$ attains its supremum (over $D$) at $x_*$.